# Azure Information Protection /Rights Management Services SDK 2.1 - Cannot Enable Document Tracking

Tags: c#, c++, azure, winapi, rights-management

I am developing an application that uses the Rights Management Services SDK 2.1 protect files loosely based on the ProtectFilesInDir project found at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Azure-Information-Protection-Samples

I have successfully set everything up and am able to protect documents, however, I have been unable to register these documents for tracking as detailed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/tracking-content

I can use the method IpcfEncryptFileWithMetadata (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn974052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but only if the pLicenseMetadata is null. As soon as I try and add any Metadata for the encryption (i.e. to enable the tracking) I am given the following error:

Your account doesn't have the required permission to complete the operation. Contact the content owner for this permission. HRESULT: 0x80040211"

Is additional setup / code required to allow the automated tracking of documents via https://portal.azurerms.com/ ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you are trying is currently not supported. Currently, it is possible to enable tracking for documents when the user is in session. A service cannot do this today. We have it in our plans to work on this. But currently there is no estimated date.